# Azure: Revoke an access token for a user so they can't request data from a mobile back-end in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, mobile, azure-active-directory, backend

Simply put, i am following official [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0) to fulfill a straight forward task of;

***How to revoke an access token for a user so they can't request data from a mobile back end in azure***

However, even following the provided guidance, nothing is happening.

I know there are policies that can be created in Azure with lesser time-spans but thought it would be possible to just revoke a users token.

Web apps seem to be catered for but not Client Apps.

Code Example:

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "a1d91a49-70c6-4d1d-a80a-b74c820a9a33"
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command only revokes the `RefreshToken` which can be used to obtain a new `AccessToken`. It does not revoke `AccessTokens`. Applications are not validating every JWT access token against AAD every time, they only validate the signature. This is why access tokens are usually given out with a much lower lifetime than the refresh tokens.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of doing it another way?